# image over another image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have 2 image I want to put one image over another my xml follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:src="@drawable/bg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imgText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="test string"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:background="@drawable/shelf" />
```

**Layout looks like this**

[image]

I want this first image over this second image.so that it looks like that this first image is standing over second image

Comment: use relative layout + frame layout or relativelayout alone.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, switch the places of the 2 images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/shelf"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:background="@drawable/shelf" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:src="@drawable/bg" />
```

Comment: I don't know why people downlon voted me I am new here that's why I asked this

Answer (score 2):

Change Layout Linear to Relative or FramLayout and add Margin Top in views.
In relative layout each and every control Automatically over its above control.
Try below code.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imgText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="test string"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]